# Find proportion of two vectors/arrays which overlap

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, similarity

I have two vectors, for example:

```
a = 25,26,37,36,27,33,104,44,40,49,45,48,50,55,56,59,54,57,105,64,73,76,72,67,68,71,78,82,77,79,86,84,83,85,91,92,96,97,102,101,93,98,99,100,94,95,88,87,65,66,90,89,80,81,75,74,69,70,62,63,61,60,58,53,52,46,51,47,41,43,42,39,38,35,34,13,14,4,5,9,8,12,3,1,2,6,7,10,11,15,21,22,29,32,31,30,28,23,103,20,24,19,16,17,18

b = 1,2,6,7,10,11,15,103,21,22,29,30,31,32,33,28,23,20,12,19,24,27,16,17,18,25,26,36,37,42,41,43,46,52,53,58,57,54,51,47,44,104,40,49,45,48,50,55,56,59,105,62,63,70,69,74,75,81,73,76,80,86,79,77,72,64,67,68,71,78,82,83,84,85,91,92,96,97,101,102,93,89,90,98,99,100,95,94,88,87,66,65,61,60,39,38,35,34,14,13,4,5,9,8,3
```

and I would like to find their commonality, based on the numbers which are next to each other. Both vectors always contain the same numbers as each other, but in a different order.

For example, in both `a` , the numbers `39,38,35,34,13,14,4,5,9,8` are next to each other and in `b` there is a sequence `39,38,35,34,14,13,4,5,9,8`, which is almost the same, save the position of the 13 and 14. So, since there are 10 numbers in this sequence and two are in the wrong order, I might say that this segment of the vectors has an 80% similarity. Is there a way to do this for the entirety of the vectors?

I know there is something in biology, called the sequence similarity, but I can't quite link it to this.

Comment: It sounds like you're simply looking for the proportion of the elements which are succeeded by the same element in each sequence. (Equivalently, the number of times you'd need to snip the first sequence before rearranging the substrings to form the second sequence).

Comment: Do you have constraints on the minimum numbers in the common sequence, for example at least 4? And what is the maximum size of the input vectors?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: People who need to analyse and compare DNA face a lot of problems like this, and so there are tools specifically for this. I don't recommend you write your own algorithm, as it would be quite complex to account for all the different possibilities of "similarity". Instead, use a library like [BioPython](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.pairwise2.html)

Comment: For instance: `from Bio import pairwise2; a = [25,26,37,...]; b = [1,2,6,...]; alignments = pairwise2.align.globalxx(a, b, gap_char=['-']); print(alignments[0])` will print: `Alignment(seqA=['-', '-', '-', ..., 20, 24, 19, 16, 17, 18], seqB=[1, 2, 6, 7, 10, 11, ..., '-', '-', '-', '-'], score=48.0, start=0, end=162)` (I replaced part of the output with `...` manually so it fits in comments), which tells you that it was able to align 48 characters successfully.

Comment: Yeah, Sneftel, that's what I am trying to do, and there aren't constraints on the minimum numbers in the common sequence, L. Meyer, and vectors are of maximum size  approx 1000. I think that should do it, thanks @Stef! I am actually programming in R though, do you know a function which would do the same?

Comment: @purecobalt Apparently there is a library "Biostrings" for R, but I've never used it